# Missing Variables

Tags: random-numbers, variable

In this code, I've created three lists of random numbers... but for some reason, they only show up some of the time.

What's happening?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\pagestyle{empty}

\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\newcommand{\InitVariablesGCF}
{%
 \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{ListA}{{1}{3}{5}{7}{11}}
 \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{ListB}{{10}{20}{40}{60}{80}{90}}
 \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{ListC}{{000}{111}{222}{333}{444}{555}{666}} 
 \pgfmathrandomitem{\RandomA}{ListA}
 \pgfmathrandomitem{\RandomB}{ListB}
 \pgfmathrandomitem{\RandomC}{ListC}
}

\newcommand{\ShowMeThree}
{%
\InitVariablesGCF
\RandomA , \RandomB , \RandomC 

\vspace{1cm}
}

\newcommand{\ManyShowMeThrees}[1]
{\foreach \x in {1,...,#1} {\ShowMeThree}}

\begin{document}

\ManyShowMeThrees{50}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a `\show` as in

```
\newcommand{\ShowMeThree}
{%
\InitVariablesGCF
\show\RandomA
\RandomA , \RandomB , \RandomC 

\vspace{1cm}
}
```

then you quickly see the problem

```
> \RandomA=macro:
->\csname pgfmath@randomlist@ListA@\pgfmath@randomtemp \endcsname .
```

so your `\RandomA` is defined to access item `\pgfmath@randomtemp` but you access another random item before using this command so `\pgfmath@randomtemp` ends up always being the value from the last call.

If you save each value before the next computation it works better

```
\newcommand{\InitVariablesGCF}
{%
 \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{ListA}{{1}{3}{5}{7}{11}}%
 \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{ListB}{{10}{20}{40}{60}{80}{90}}%
 \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{ListC}{{000}{111}{222}{333}{444}{555}{666}}% 
 \pgfmathrandomitem{\RandomA}{ListA}\edef\RandomA{\RandomA}%
 \pgfmathrandomitem{\RandomB}{ListB}\edef\RandomB{\RandomB}%
 \pgfmathrandomitem{\RandomC}{ListC}\edef\RandomC{\RandomC}%
}
```

(I also added the missing `%`)

[image]

Comment: I think I understand your description of the problem, but do not understand your solution, even though I recognize that it works. `\pgfmathrandomitem{\RandomA}{ListA}\edef\RandomA{\RandomA}%`   seems to me like it starts out the same way my code does, but then defines `\RandomA` as `\RandomA`... How does this help? Doesn't `\pgfmathrandomitem{\RandomA}{ListA}` already define `\RandomA` as an element from `ListA`?

Comment: Also, I don't recall having this problem of "access items" previously. Is there something unusual about the code here causing that problem? It seems weird that it would be a problem given that my code specifically names different lists to pick from. I sometimes hear that `LaTeX` is a hard and old-fashioned language, so perhaps it just doesn't necessarily take care of such things automatically.

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything nothing to do with latex particularly it's just the way the pgfmathrandomitem macro is apparently defined. You would see the same if you were using plain tex or context not latex.

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything arguably it's a bug in pgf and it ought to have an extra level of expansion so that pgfmathrandomitem did not have this problem. You could report it.

Comment: Who would I report this to?

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything page 27 of the tikz manual has contact details